# Conditional formatting using vlookup or Countifs

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to use conditional formatting to see if an entry on A1-A10 is found on Sheet2!A1-A10. If it is then I want it to apply conditional formatting for every cell that it is found in on A1-A10. Every solution I have found so far is asking to use a < or > 0 which doesn't work.

This is what I've started with. I know this doesn't work but I am not sure where to go from here.

=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A1:Sheet2!A10), $A$1:$A$10, 1, FALSE)

Comment: Wrap the `VLOOKUP` in `ISERROR` - though `COUNTIF` should work here. Maybe [edit] your question with what you actually tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
 =NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10;1;FALSE)))
```

When you add a formula for conditional formatting, you write it as if it concernes only the first cell of the range, i.e. A1 in this case, although the formatting rule is applied to A1:A10.

[image]